# Make postfix trigger a php script using always_bcc

Tags: php, postfix, ubuntu-12.04

I have been having a VERY hard time with this, have searched everywhere, and in utter desperation am posting this question.

I am using postfix and dovecot on ubuntu 12.04. I am trying very hard to trigger a php script which runs any time a new email is received by the server. In my /etc/postfix/main.cf I have added the line:

```
always_bcc = new_incoming_email@localhost
```

In /etc/aliases I have the line:

```
new_incoming_email: "|/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/file/new_incoming_email.php"
```

In /etc/postfix/vmaps I have the line:

```
new_incoming_email@localhost localhost/new_incoming_email/
```

When I run the file from the command-line I can see that the file works, as it adds a line to a log file as part of its function. From the command-line I type: /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/file/new_incoming_email.php

Here's what I get in /var/log/mail.log when I send an email to the server:

```
Feb  1 04:20:52 myserver postfix/smtpd[3090]: connect from nm40-vm4.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com[72.30.239.212]
Feb  1 04:20:52 myserver postfix/smtpd[3090]: C1EDD20630: client=nm40-vm4.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com[72.30.239.212]
Feb  1 04:20:52 myserver postfix/cleanup[3004]: C1EDD20630: message-id=<1577234103.395093.1422764451476.JavaMail.yahoo@mail.yahoo.com>
Feb  1 04:20:52 myserver postfix/qmgr[1092]: C1EDD20630: from=<sending_addres@yahoo.com>, size=24383, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Feb  1 04:20:52 myserver postfix/error[3008]: C1EDD20630: to=<new_incoming_email@localhost.com>, relay=none, delay=0.22, delays=0.18/0/0/0.04, dsn=4.4.1, status=defferred (delivery temporarilyferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to localhost.com[74.125.224.72]:25: Connection timed out) suspended: connect to localhost.com[74.125.224.72]:25: Connection timed out)
Feb  1 04:20:52 myserver postfix/virtual[3092]: C1EDD20630: to=<receiving_address@example.com>, relay=virtual, delay=0.22, delays=0.18/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Feb  1 04:20:53 myserver postfix/smtpd[3090]: disconnect from nm40-vm4.bullet.mail.bf1.yahoo.com[72.30.239.212]
```

With example.com is domain that exist in my server.

Here is the output of "postconf -n:"

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
always_bcc = new_incoming_email@localhost
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
default_privs = johnvision
default_transport = smtp
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 108.171.187.9
myorigin = $myhostname
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_host_lookup = native
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu/GNU)
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/vhosts
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps
virtual_minimum_uid = 1000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

I have been trying to get this working for quite some time. Actually, I DID have it working a while back, but I have changed something on the server (not exactly sure what) and since then it has not been working.

I really need some help with this.

Comment: Where is the rest of the log entry? You cut them off at the right side.

Comment: I edited my post with the cut-off parts included.

Comment: Please post the output of `postconf -n`. Looks like something wrong with your configuration

Comment: I have edited my post to include output of postconf -n.

Comment: Anyway, `new_incoming_email@localhost` entry in ` /etc/postfix/vmaps` is useless because the localhost was defined in `mydestination` not in `virtual_mailbox_domains`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based of your maillog, I can see that postfix rewrites `always_bcc` target from new_incoming_email@**localhost** to new_incoming_email@**localhost.com**. That caused postfix complain with error

```
(delivery temporarily deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to localhost.com[74.125.224.72]:25: Connection timed out)
```

The parameter who responsible for this rewriting is [append_dot_mydomain](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#append_dot_mydomain), with default value is **yes**. When the value is **yes**, postfix will append the string `.$mydomain` to addresses that have no ".domain" information. That's why *new_incoming_email script* never be triggered.

#### Solution

Put `append_dot_mydomain = no` in *main.cf* should make postfix doesn't alter the domain like before.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much...I've been at this for hours, and you've put an end to my problem!